# navigate.getParam doesn't work when calling from the constructor in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem when calling navigation.getParam from the super constructor, before I immediately use

```
export default class HomeBeranda extends Component {...}
```

but when I change to

```
class HomeBeranda extends Component {...}
```

and call at the end of the code with:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
   render () {
     return <HomeBeranda />;
   }
}
```

instead an error appears **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.getParam)**

This is my full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, TextInput, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, AsyncStorage, BackHandler, ImageBackground, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

class HomeBeranda extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      akun: '',
      namapendek: '',
      email: '',
      rupiah: '',
      transaksi: '',
    }

    const { navigation } = props;
    if (navigation.getParam('akun').length > 0) {
      this.state = {
        akun: navigation.getParam('akun'),
      }
      this._callApiInfo(navigation.getParam('akun'));
    } else {
      this._showData();
    }
  }

  _showData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('akun');
      this.setState({
        akun: value,
      });
      this._callApiInfo(value);
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error);
    }
  };

  _callApiInfo(value) {
    const paramsDatac = new URLSearchParams();
    paramsDatac.append('akun', value);
    Axios.post('http://radarugi.com/rekber/info.php', paramsDatac)
    .then(function (response) {
      const arrayHasil = JSON.stringify(response);
      const arrayLagi = JSON.parse(arrayHasil);
      this.setState({
        namapendek: arrayLagi.data.namaPendek,
        transaksi: arrayLagi.data.transaksi,
        rupiah: arrayLagi.data.rupiah,
        email: arrayLagi.data.email,
      });
      AsyncStorage.setItem('namapendek', this.state.namapendek);
      AsyncStorage.setItem('transaksi', this.state.transaksi);
      AsyncStorage.setItem('rupiah', this.state.rupiah);
      AsyncStorage.setItem('email', this.state.email);
      //Alert.alert(value);
    }.bind(this))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove();
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Keluar',
      'Apakah anda ingin keluar dari aplikasi?',
      [
        { text: 'Batal', onPress: () => console.log('Batal'), style: 'cancel' },
        { text: 'Ya', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() },
      ],
      { cancelable: false });
    return true;
  }

  _fungsiSetAkun(data) {
    this.setState({
      akun: data,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="height" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#EE2562" barStyle="light-content" />
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: 130, width: 320, borderRadius: 12, marginTop: 12, shadowColor: 'black', shadowRadius: 5, shadowOpacity: 0.7, elevation: 12 }}>
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'BEBAS', fontSize: 40, marginLeft: 9, marginTop: 4 }}>Hai <Text style={{color: '#EE2562', fontFamily: 'BEBAS', fontSize: 40, marginLeft: 9, marginTop: 4}}>{this.state.namapendek}</Text></Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}}>
              <View style={{borderTopWidth: 1, borderRightWidth: 1, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Text style={{fontFamily: 'BEBAS', fontSize: 33, color: '#EE2562'}}>{this.state.rupiah}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{borderTopWidth: 1, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Text style={{fontFamily: 'BEBAS', fontSize: 24, color: '#EE2562', textAlign: 'center'}}>{this.state.transaksi}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#EE2562', height: 90, top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, position: 'absolute', }}>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: '#EE2562', marginTop: 45, height: 80, marginHorizontal: 20, borderRadius: 4, opacity: 1, shadowColor: 'black', shadowOpacity: 0.7, shadowRadius: 3, elevation: 8, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', fontFamily: 'BEBAS', fontSize: 50, paddingLeft: 8}}>Bikin Rekber</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: '#EE2562', marginTop: 25, height: 80, marginHorizontal: 20, borderRadius: 4, opacity: 1, shadowColor: 'black', shadowOpacity: 0.7, shadowRadius: 3, elevation: 8, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', fontFamily: 'BEBAS', fontSize: 50, paddingLeft: 8}}>Join Rekber</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 3, marginTop: 30, marginHorizontal: 20, height: 200}}>
          <ScrollView>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 4, fontSize: 17, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            Panduan Singkat:
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 4, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            1. Penjual menekan tombol "Bikin Rekber" untuk memulai Rekber (Perlu diingat, fitur ini khusus dipakai oleh pihak Penjual)
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 1, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            2. Isi semua kolom sesuai dengan apa yang akan ditransaksikan
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 1, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            3. Ketika keluar kode Rekber, salin kode tersebut dan kasih ke Pembeli (Rahasiakan kode tersebut dari orang lain)
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 1, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            4. Pembeli menekan tombol "Join Rekber" dan masukkan kode dari Penjual
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 1, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            5. Proses Rekber sudah dimulai, saatnya Pembeli transfer dana/uang sesuai dengan nominal yang diberikan ke rekening Rekber (pihak ketiga)
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 1, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            6. Ketika sudah melakukan transfer sesuai nominal ke rekening Rekber, maka pembeli harus menekan tombol "Sudah Bayar", sistem akan mendeteksi apakah dana/uang sudah masuk ke rekening Rekber atau belum
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 1, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            7. Ketika sistem telah memverifikasi transferan pembeli, maka Penjual akan diberi pemberitahuan untuk memberikan barang/akun (jualan nya) ke Pembeli
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 1, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            8. Setelah memberikan barang/akun (jualan nya) tersebut ke Pembeli, Penjual harus menekan tombol "Barang Dikirim"
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 1, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            9. Pembeli harus memastikan barang/akun yang diberi oleh Penjual sesuai dengan apa yang ia inginkan. Jika sudah sesuai, maka Pembeli harus menekan tombol "Barang Diterima"
           </Text>
           <Text style={{textAlign: 'left', marginTop: 1, fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 7, color: 'black'}}>
            10. Setelah Pembeli menekan tombol "Barang Diterima", sistem kami akan mengirim dana/uang sesuai nominal ke rekening milik Penjual
           </Text>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: 60, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0, position: 'absolute', shadowColor: 'black', shadowRadius: 9, shadowOpacity: 0.7, elevation: 10, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Icon name="md-home" size={40} color="#EE2562"/>
              <Text style={{fontFamily: "BEBAS", color: "#EE2562"}}>Home</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Icon name="md-list-box" size={40} color="black"/>
              <Text style={{fontFamily: "BEBAS", color: "black"}}>History</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Icon name="md-person" size={40} color="black"/>
              <Text style={{fontFamily: "BEBAS", color: "black"}}>Account</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <HomeBeranda />;
  }
}
```

and this is my error screenshoot:
[Proof:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cojry.jpg)

Comment: well you expect `navigation` as a prop, but when you render your component in `return <HomeBeranda />;` you're not passing `navigation` as a prop

Comment: how do i fix this?

Comment: well. you need to pass down `navigation` to your `<HomeBeranda />` component but.. `navigation` is not defined anywhere in your code. Where does it comes from?

Comment: in the previous screen I have code like this:
`this.props.navigation.navigate ('HomeWelcome', {akun: this.state.akun});` so the code invokes my other screen while sending the "akun" parameter

Comment: docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Answer (score 0):

As @Gonzalo suggested, you're trying to access a `prop` which is never passed into your component. I see that you're using React Navigation, I strongly suggest to follow their excellent [getting started guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html) which will walk you through setting up your Navigators (which will then pass down the `navigation` prop to your components).

Comment: React Navigation is based around different navigators, such as Stack, Tab and Switch. You need to setup the navigation flow of your app to be able to navigate to different screens using the `navigation` prop. These navigators will handle passing it to your screens.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return <HomeBeranda {...this.props} />;
        }
      }
```

It will help you.